# How to trigger enlarged mouse pointer without shaking the mouse

Tags: mouse, accessibility, cursor

There's a feature on OS X at least since El Capitan, but possibly earlier that enlarges the mouse pointer when you shake the mouse. In fact, it's called **Shake mouse pointer to locate** (under **Accessibility** > **Display**) and it's enabled by default.

I want to be able to briefly "pulse" the size of the pointer to draw attention to something on screen, but without moving the pointer away from what I am trying to highlight.

I know that there are 3rd party add-ons that do this sort of thing by drawing stuff on the screen where the pointer is, but does anybody know if it's possible to trigger the built-in OS mouse enlargement briefly other than by shaking the mouse?